# OpenID Claimed identifier

Tags: python, node.js, openid

When authenticating with OpenID I am afaict supposed to use the [claimed identifier](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#identifying) as a key to uniquely identify a specific user. The problem I am having with this is either two independent bugs or a misunderstanding of the spec :).

When using [node openid](https://github.com/havard/node-openid) I would expect these two URLs to result in the same claimed_id:

- http://{username}.myopenid.com/
- http://www.myopenid.com/xrds?username={username}.myopenid.com

However, those URLs result in two different claimed_ids:

- http://{username}.myopenid.com/
- http://www.myopenid.com/xrds?username={username}.myopenid.com

both being the URLs mentioned. To verify this behaviour I decided to check out a different OpenID library, [Python OpenID](https://github.com/openid/python-openid). Using the same two URLs I still get two claimed_ids, but in this case they're different, now I get:

- http://{username}.myopenid.com/
- http://{username}.myopenid.com/xrds

So, I guess my questions is, am I right in assuming the claimed_ids *should* be used as identifiers and that the above URLs *should* result in the same claimed_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason they should result in the same claimed id and in fact you offer nothing in support of that expectation.

However, it should be noted that the first library uses a wrong value for the claimed id (emphasis mine):

> 7.2.  Normalization
>
> The end user's input MUST be normalized into an Identifier, as follows :
>
> (...)
>
> 4. URL Identifiers MUST then be further normalized by (...) *following redirects* when retrieving their content (...).

And for the second URL you have this response (some headers removed):

```
> GET /xrds?username=cataphract.myopenid.com HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.myopenid.com
> Accept: application/xrds+xml
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://cataphract.myopenid.com/xrds
```

Therefore `http://{username}.myopenid.com/xrds` should be used.

Comment: So one of them were misbehaving, good, that means I haven't completely lost my mind :). Thanks for the help.